# Selecting records from a date which just precedes a given date and multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

In the following table, there is the tracking for a particular R_ID and F_ID. Col_C = '10' marks the final entry in the cycle. ENTRY = '1' means new entry and ENTRY = '2' means modifying existing entry on the same date. ENTRY = '2' means it is the most recent entry

```
F_ID    R_ID    DATE    ENTRY   Col_A   Col_B   Col_C   Score_1    Score_2  Score_3
85     158   20161005    1       99      99      01        0         0        0
85     158   20161010    1       01      99      99        3         2        2
85     158   20161010    2       01      99      99        3         2        2
85     158   20161012    1       01      01      99        3         2        2
85     158   20161012    2       01      01      99        3         2        2
85     158   20161019    1       99      02      99        3         2        2
85     158   20161022    1       99      99      10        3         2        2
85     158   20161022    2       99      99      10        3         1        2
```

I need to select such that I get records for

```
 1. The most recent final entry i.e Col_C = '10' 
and if Col_C = '10' and ENTRY = '1' or '2' for the same DATE 
then select the one with ENTRY = '2'

and

 2. records with Col_A or Col_B = '01' and Col_C != '10' 
where the date just precedes(before) the DATE of final entry. 
Also if Col_A or Col_B = '01'and if ENTRY = '1' or '2' for the same DATE 
then select the one with ENTRY = '2'
```

For results I'm looking for something like

```
F_ID   R_ID    DATE    ENTRY   Col_A   Col_B   Col_C   Score_1    Score_2  Score_3
85     158   20161012    2       01      01      99        3         2        2
85     158   20161022    2       99      99      10        3         1        2
```

I tried the following

```
select * from tbl T where Col_C = '10' and T.date=(select min (T2.date) from tbl T2 where T2.Col_C = '10' and T2.R_ID = T.R_ID
           and T2.F_ID = T.F_ID)


union 


select * from
(
select *
from tbl k
where (k.Col_A = '01' or k.Col_B = '01')
  and k.Col_A <> k.Col_B
  and k.Col_C <> '10'
  k.date =
        (select min (k2.date) from tbl k2
           where (k2.Col_A='01' or k2.Col_B='01') and 
           k2.Col_A <> k2.Col_B and 
           k2.Col_C <> '10' and
           k2.R_ID = k.R_ID
           and k2.F_ID = k.F_ID
        )


union 

select *
  from tbl  S
  where S.Col_A = '01' and S.Col_B = '01' and S.Col_C <> '10'
    and S.date =
        (select min (S2.date) from tbl S2
           where S2.Col_A='01' and S2.Col_B='01' and S2.Col_C <> '10' and
           S2.R_ID = S.R_ID
           and S2.F_ID = S.F_ID
        )
)
```

I am unable to pin down the logic for the latest final entry(Col_C = '10' with recent date) and preceding entry(Col_A or Col_B = '01' for a date just preceding final entry)

I will need 2 records for each F_ID, R_ID. One final entry and one preceding entry

Thanks.

Comment: and what have you tried so far? Please post your attempts; questions like "how to do this" without showing any effort are not usually welcome here

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query -

```
SELECT F_ID, R_ID, DATE, MAX(ENTRY), Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, Score_1, Score_2, Score_3
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE Col_C = '10'
GROUP BY DATE
UNION ALL
SELECT F_ID, R_ID, DATE, MAX(ENTRY), Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, Score_1, Score_2, Score_3
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE (Col_A = '01' OR Col_B = '01')
AND Col_C <> 10
GROUP BY DATE
HAVING DATE < MAX(DATE)
```

Though I have not tried this query but I think this can help you.